# getting "mysql server has gone away" error when making two connection to the same database

Tags: c++, mysql

I got "mysql server has gone away" error when I created two connections to the same database from the same process and try to access them. I've searched for solution on the Internet, and it says it may be caused by server timeout or too large query. But in my case, these are not the problem.

Following are my actual code.
I created two objects(deleter and copier) of ContentsCopyCopier. init() function makes connection to the database which is specified in the configFile. As the two objects uses same configFile, the connected to the same database. I run deleter in another thread and run copier in the current thread.

```
int main(){
    ...
    ContentsCopyCopier deleter(configFile);
    log_.write(LogType::INFO, "Start to initialize deleter");
    if(!deleter.init())
    {
        log_.write(LogType::ERROR, "Failed to initialize deleter.");
        return 1;
    }
    std::thread delete_thread(&ContentsCopyCopier::runDeleteThread, deleter);

    ContentsCopyCopier copier(configFile);
    /* Initialize ContentsCopyCopier */
    log_.write(LogType::INFO, "Start to initialize ContentsCopyCopier.");
    if(!copier.init())
    {
        log_.write(LogType::ERROR, "Failed to initialize ContentsCopyCopier.");
        return 1;
    }
    log_.write(LogType::INFO, "Initialize ContentsCopyCopier successfully.");

    /* Start to run ContentsCopyCopier */   
    log_.write(LogType::INFO, "Start to run ContentsCopyCopier.");
    if(!copier.run())
    {
        log_.write(LogType::ERROR, "Failed to run ContentsCopyCopier.");
        return 1;
    }
    log_.write(LogType::INFO, "Run ContentsCopyCopier successfully.");

    return 0;
}
```

In the init() function, I make the connection. db_ is a member variable of the class ContentsCopyCopier.

```
bool ContentsCopyCopier::init(){
    ...
    /* Connect to mysql */
    if(!db_.connect(param_.mysql_host, param_.mysql_database, param_.mysql_user, param_.mysql_password))
    {
        log_.write(LogType::ERROR,"Failed to connect to MySQL.");
        return false; 
    }
    ...
}

MySQLConnection::MySQLConnection()
{
    bool reconnect = true;
    conn = mysql_init(NULL);
    mysql_options(conn, MYSQL_OPT_RECONNECT, &reconnect);
}

bool MySQLConnection::connect(std::string host, std::string database, std::string user, std::string password)
{
    if(!mysql_real_connect(conn, host.c_str(), user.c_str(),password.c_str(), database.c_str(), 0, NULL, 0)){
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

MySQLConnection::~MySQLConnection()
{
    mysql_close(conn);
}
```

When I run this function in a new thread I got the "mysql server has gone away" error.

```
void ContentsCopyCopier::runDeleteThread()
{
    try{
        db_.updateDeleting1MediaFilesToDisabled1(hostName_);  <-  here is the position I got the error
    }catch(MySQLException e){
        log_.write(LogType::ERROR, e.detail + "(" + e.query + ")");
        log_.write(LogType::ERROR, e.msg);
        return; 
    }
    ...
}

void MySQLConnection::updateDeleting1MediaFilesToDisabled1(std::string stock)
{
    std::string query = "UPDATE mediafiles ";
    query += " SET Status='" + DISABLED1 + "',";
    query += " UpdateDate='" + getCurrentTime() + "'";
    query += " WHERE Status ='" + DELETING_1 + "' AND Stock = '" + stock + "';";

    // Execute a sql statement
    if (mysql_query(conn, query.c_str())) {
        MySQLException e;
        e.detail = mysql_error(conn);
        e.query = query;
        e.msg = "Failed to update status from deleting_1 to disabled_1.";
        throw e;
    }
}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Unrelated, but your updateDeleting1MediaFilesToDisabled1 is a gigantic SQL injection vulnerability waiting to happen.

Comment: According to the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/8.0/en/mysql-thread-init.html), your `delete_thread` should call mysql_thread_init to initialize thread-specific state.

Comment: You are right. I called init() function in the new thread and it's working now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was solved by calling the `mysql_thread_init` function in the new thread, which initialized MySQL per-thread state.